# If there are 4 child process in Python Multiprocessing Pool, How can I make sure all worker run task at least one time

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I used multiprocessing pool in Python3 to connect database(Postgresql).I created database connections with multiprocessing.Pool(8,init_dbconn),and do some dml with pool.map(update, records).Obviously I can get better performance if I do commit after pool.map rather than each iteration in pool.map().So I define another function to call dbconnection.commit,and run pool.map(func_commit, range(8), 1) after pool.map(update),but I found the pool don't distribute tasks to each child process at least one time, even I increase the size or range() to do more iteration. So some of database connection didn't commit the dml.
Is there any method to achieve this function?

The pseudo-code like this:

```
def conn_db():
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(database="dbname", user="username", password="pass", host="127.0.0.1", port="5432")
        return (conn)
    except:
        print(traceback.format_exc())

def init_proc():
    global conn
    conn = conn_db()
    global cursor
    cursor = conn.cursor()


def double2(i):
    print ("I'm process:%s, %s" % (os.getpid(), multiprocessing.current_process()))
    return i*2

    
def exec_ten_parallel(num_parallel, records):
    try:
        pool = Pool(8, initializer=init_proc)
        t1_b = time.time()  
        pool.imap(double2, range(16), 1)
        #for i in range(16):
        #    pool.apply_async(double2,(1,))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        t1_runtime = time.time() - t1_b
        #print('update all count:', len(records), 'seconds:', t1_runtime)
    except:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
```

I print the worker name and pid, as shown below

```
I'm process:53141, <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
I'm process:53141, <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
I'm process:53142, <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
I'm process:53141, <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
I'm process:53141, <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
I'm process:53142, <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
I'm process:53141, <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
I'm process:53141, <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
[root@dc3-06-005 dml-test]# python3 bak-p.py 
I'm process:53164, <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
I'm process:53164, <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
I'm process:53164, <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
I'm process:53164, <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
I'm process:53164, <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
I'm process:53164, <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
I'm process:53164, <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
I'm process:53164, <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
```

Almost could not run all ForkPoolWorker, just only call one or two worker do job.

Comment: I had tried map,it gave similar result. I tried all the function of Pool except starmap()

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about using [multiprocessing.Barrier](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Barrier), you pass it in the initializer with the number of processes in the pool, then inside the function just call the `wait()` method of it, just make sure the function has `chunksize=1` and is called exactly the number of child processes, orelse everything will hang.

to avoid the hanging, you can pass a timeout, but you will also have to catch the error that will be raised if the timeout runs out ... so its not the safest approach, but totally doable.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import traceback
import os
import multiprocessing

def double2(i):
    global gbarrier
    print ("I'm process:%s, %s" % (os.getpid(), multiprocessing.current_process()))
    gbarrier.wait()
    return i*2

def init_func(barrier):
    global gbarrier
    gbarrier = barrier

def exec_ten_parallel():
    try:
        barrier = multiprocessing.Barrier(8)
        pool = Pool(8,initializer=init_func,initargs=(barrier,))
        t1_b = time.time()
        pool.imap(double2, range(8), chunksize=1)
        #for i in range(16):
        #    pool.apply_async(double2,(1,))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        t1_runtime = time.time() - t1_b
        #print('update all count:', len(records), 'seconds:', t1_runtime)
    except:
        print(traceback.format_exc())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    exec_ten_parallel()
```

```
I'm process:6396, <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-2' parent=12688 started daemon>
I'm process:13612, <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-4' parent=12688 started daemon>
I'm process:14848, <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-8' parent=12688 started daemon>
I'm process:6836, <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-1' parent=12688 started daemon>
I'm process:12632, <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-6' parent=12688 started daemon>
I'm process:1536, <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-3' parent=12688 started daemon>
I'm process:11856, <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-5' parent=12688 started daemon>
I'm process:13888, <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-7' parent=12688 started daemon>
```

if you want a safer approach, then perhaps for the normal runtime have a counter on every process that will commit every 100 operations or something, and only call this dangerous function when you absolutely have to, in short it should work out of the box, but inside the production environment you must handle the "one time it will fail because a cosmic ray crashed a process before it reached the barrier" sort of error, otherwise you must make your own `multiprocess.Pool` using multiple `multiprocess.Process`

**Edit:** moved the wait to the end of function instead of its start, for faster out-of-order execution, also imap is fine if you don't want to block the main process.

**Edit2:** in order to make the barrier safe to use, you have to join the threads before attempting this command, and you have to pass a timeout, and wrap it in a try block, and catch the timeout error in each process, then each process will return a success flag, and the main process will then detect the command failure and join the pool again before redoing this command again, this is how it should be done in a production environment to avoid failure, its failure should happen once every few months/years, but this is the way to solve it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've learned so much from your reply.  If I use `multiprocessing.Process`, how can I change the Process's attribute `target=fun`, because I wanna do 'func-update' first,then run 'func_commit'. And I don't figure out how to iterate with all child processes right now, like the implementation of  `pool.map()`

Comment: @JerryChen actually you cannot do that, the function of `pool` is actually an infinite loop, and commands are sent through a `multiprocessing.queue`, the way you can modify this if you create your own pool implementation, is between checking for commands on queue you can have each process check a `multiprocess.Event` that only belongs to this process to know if it should do a commit instead of reading commands from the queue, so if there are 8 processes, there will be 8 Events, and the parent will set them all and the children will clear them when they finish the operation.

Comment: @JerryChen while using the barrier is not very safe, you can make it safe by just taking the right precautions, like wrapping it in a try block to catch the error, and provide a proper timeout, and joining the pool before submitting this command, and have the processes return a bool representing the operation success, and have the parent check this flag and repeat the operation if it failed after joining the pool again, the warning in the answer is for people to understand the risks they may run into when using it, not to discourage is use,  its failure can be catastrophic for the ill-informed

Comment: really appreciate your guide and reply,I will try the advice that you gave.